# Fail to connect Flex-

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have deployed a Java EE application on JBoss-5.1.0. To have extra security I have fronted the JBoss with Apache + enabled ssl. Tomcat talks to server using (AJP 1.3 on port 8001). So my configuration looks like:

```
tomcat:443 (ssl) ---|--- Jboss:8080 (IpAddress:8080) (http)
```

This configuation seems to work well for all static and Dynamic pages except for flex part.
My problems begin when I try access anything on flex part. The AMF channels fail and I can see the following stack trace on server log:

> 2012-04-13 16:19:50,940 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/catissuecore].[MessageBrokerServlet]] (ajp-127.0.0.1-8009-4) Servlet.service() for servlet MessageBrokerServlet threw exception
>   flex.messaging.security.SecurityException: **Secure endpoint '/messagebroker/amfsecure' must be contacted via a secure protocol.** 
>           at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.validateRequestProtocol(AbstractEndpoint.java:862)
>           at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.service(AbstractEndpoint.java:630)
>           at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint.service(AMFEndpoint.java:99)
>           at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.service(MessageBrokerServlet.java:424)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>           at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)
>           at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:384)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I have defined following channels in remote-config.xml:

```
 <default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-amf"/>
     <channel ref="my-secure-amf"/>
 </default-channels>
```

And my services-config.xml has following configuration

```
 <channels>
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint uri="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <polling-enabled>false</polling-enabled>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>

    <channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
        <endpoint uri="https://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfsecure" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <!--HTTPS requests on some browsers do not work when pragma "no-cache" are set-->
            <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

Has anyone face this issue?

Any pointer will be of great use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I allow only HTTPS traffic and all these HTTPS traffic was allowed to route through ssl enabled Apache server. Also I have a load balancer which talks to Apache sending HTTP request instead of HTTPS request, which was the root cause of problem. I changed the setting of load balancer and it works properly.

Exception: Secure endpoint '/messagebroker/amfsecure' must be contacted via a secure protocol.

1. This exception itself says that you are trying to connect to a flex client over an unsecure protocol to a secure endpoint.
2. A secure endpoint receives messages/request from clients and decodes them, then sends them on to a MessageBroker for routing to a service. So here the request is not encrypted, secure endpoint will throw an exception, since while decoding the request is assumed to be an encrypted one.

There are two solutions:

- Find out why unsecure request is sent to a secure endpoint. And try to fix this issue. For this you might need to monitor all requests  sent and recieved.
- Open services-config.xml file and change the endpoint classname of a flex secure channel to 'flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint'. By changing this you are telling the flex client to handle all requests over an unsecure endpoint. Do this if you don't bother about your configuration and just wanted application to be running.

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution is in the other answer, it is not obvious. If the SSL is terminated either in a load balancer or in Apache, you should switch the `secure-amf` channel definition class as follows:

```
<channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
```

to

```
<channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
```

Source: http://blogs.adobe.com/kmossman/2010/02/lcds_with_ssl_termination_with.html